# How to do so that in my shopping cart the react stock does not exceed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, rxjs

**Hi, I'm new to react and I'm doing an ecommerce, I'm having a problem,
When adding to the cart, I want to verify that it adds only if the stock is greater than 0
What problem do I have: That just subtracts the stock once the customer completes the purchase. So I need to ensure that when the user is adding products to the cart, if they go out of stock, they don't add more.
I tell my logic to develop the cart, I have a state called global cart. And I pass the productDetail (in this case it is called product)
I made a logic but it didn't work when I try to add it.
Cart is an array of objects, and productDetail (in this case product is what the variable is called) is an object.
What I need to do is for example:
I have a product that has 1 in stock. That I can add the first one, but when that one is already added to the cart, it won't let me add more.
I to notify the client add sweetAlert. Below I attach my code and an image.**

```
function handleClickAddToCart(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//start logic for stock

if (product.stock <= 0) {
  swal(
    "Por el momento no tenemos mas stock",
    "Acabamos de comunicarle a la empresa",
    "error"
  );
  return;
} */

else {
  if (cart.filter((e) => e.id === product.id).length > 0) {
    if (
      cart.filter((e) => e.id === product.id).quantity < product.stock
    ) {
      dispatch(addToCart(product));
      swal(
        "Buen trabajo!",
        "El producto fue agregado con exito!",
        "success"
      );
      return;
    } else {
      swal(
        "No tenemos más stock",
        "Acabamos de enviar un Email a la empresa correspondiente",
        "error"
      );
      return;
    }
  } else {
    dispatch(addToCart(product));
    swal(
      "Buen trabajo!",
      "El producto fue agregado con exito!",
      "success"
    );
    return;
  }
} 


//Esto es para verificar que las sedes sean iguales
if (cart.length > 0) {
  if (cart[0].businessbranchId !== product.businessbranchId) {
    swal(
      "Este producto pertenece a otra empresa",
      "Podés agregarlo como favorito para comprarlo en tu proximo carrito!",
      "error"
    );
  }
} else {
  dispatch(addToCart(product));
  swal("Buen trabajo!", "El producto fue agregado con exito!", "success");
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to software development , here i tried to help you as per your question , here is codesandbox link for you : https://codesandbox.io/s/dotsimplify-stackoverflow-dhajhd-thezj5
Let me know if you need more help

Comment: `if (cart.filter((e) => e.id === product.id).length > 0) {
      if (cart[0].quantity < product.stock) {
        dispatch(addToCart(product));
        swal("Buen trabajo!", "El producto fue agregado con exito!", "success");
        return;
      } else {
        swal(
          "No tenemos más stock",
          "Acabamos de enviar un Email a la empresa correspondiente",
          "error"
        );
        return;
      }
    } else {
      dispatch(addToCart(product));
      swal("Buen trabajo!", "El producto fue agregado con exito!", "success");
      return;
    }`

Comment: you can use this condition in handle cart on click funtion to show success and error message.

Comment: Yes, but when using this, it adds 2 products to me on the first click.